# Filtrant (not necessarily totally ordered) projective system commuting with direct sums

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Hello,

Let $R$ be a commutative (not necessarily  Noetherian) ring.
Let $I$ be a small filtrant (not necessarily totally ordered) category.
Let $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ be a projective system  of $R$-modules with *surjective* transitions maps.

Assume that the natural morphism
$(\lim_{i\in I} M_i)^{(X)}\rightarrow \lim_{i\in I}(M_i^{(X)})$
is an isomorphism for any set $X$
(where the superscript $(X)$ denotes the direct sum indexed by $X$).

Question: is it true that the projective system $(M_i)_{i\in I}$
is constant (i.e. isomorphic to its projective limit as a pro-object of $R$-modules)?  In other words, does there exist $\overline i\in I$ such that for any $j\geq \overline i$ we have 
$M_j\cong \lim_{i\in I} M_i$?

Thanks for your hints,

Luisa Fiorot

Comment: By constant, do you mean that there should exist $i$ such that $\lim M_i = M_i$ ?

Comment: I've inserted the interpretation you wrote as an answer.  It would help if you registered an account, because that would prevent you from making new user-IDs.  A new user-ID prevents you from editing your question.

Comment: Write $K_i$ for the kernel of the map $\lim M_i \to M_i$. The $K_i$ form a projective system with respect to inclusion. It seems you're asking the following : if $\lim^1 K_i^{(X)} = 0$ for any set $X$, then does $K_i$ satisfy the Mittag-Leffler condition ?

Answer (score 4):

No. There are nontrivial filtrant projective systems $(M_i)$ of $R$-modules with surjective transition maps such that $\varprojlim M_i=0$. Both $(\varprojlim M_i)^{(X)}$ and $\varprojlim(M_i^{(X)})$ may be identified with submodules of $(\varprojlim M_i)^X=0$, so the canonical map $(\varprojlim M_i)^{(X)}\to\varprojlim(M_i^{(X)})$ is an isomorphism.

For how to construct such examples, see [G. Bergman, Some Empty Inverse Limits](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/unpub/emptylim.pdf) or G. Higman, A.H. Stone, On inverse systems with trivial limits. J. Lond. Math. Soc. 29, 233-236 (1954)

There is also Bourbaki, Topologie generale, III §7 Ex. 2, but the argument given there seems to be incomplete.